# Java Server socket TCP connection stuck in CLOSE_WAIT state while client shutdown or client restart

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

While performing Client restart or shutdown,all socket connections are hang in CLOSE_WAIT on server side.
XdrAble used to send serialized data into XDR streams.
pool is object of standard KeyedSocketPool.
MAXIMUM_RETRY,MAXIMUM_RETYR_BEFORE_RESET_POOL are constants defined to reset the pool connections.
What I am missing while closing the connections?

public  RESP call (REQ request,
      RESP response, int requestLength, int timeOut) throws Exception
  {
    Socket socket = null;

```
IOException ioException = null;

short attempts = 0;
boolean needResetPool = false;

while (true)
{
  ioException = null;

  try
  {
    // Get socket (open if not connected)
    socket = (Socket) pool.borrowObject ();
    socket.setSoTimeout (timeOut);

    // Send request
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream (socket
        .getOutputStream ());
    XdrBufferEncodingStream xdrIn = new XdrBufferEncodingStream (
        requestLength);
    xdrIn.beginEncoding (socket.getInetAddress (), socket.getPort ());
    request.xdrEncode (xdrIn);
    xdrIn.endEncoding ();
    outputStream.write (xdrIn.getXdrData ());
    outputStream.flush ();
    xdrIn.close ();

    // Read response
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream (socket
        .getInputStream ());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[UreMsgBodyLength.MAXIMUM_MSG_LEN];
    int bytesRead = inputStream.read (buffer);

    if (bytesRead < UreMsgBodyLength.MESSAGE_HEADER_LEN)
      throw new IOException("Socket Read Failed - invalid bytesRead="+bytesRead);


    int encodedLength = bytesRead;
    if ( encodedLength < 0 || ( encodedLength & 3) != 0 )
      encodedLength = UreMsgBodyLength.MAXIMUM_MSG_LEN;

   XdrBufferDecodingStream xdrOut = new XdrBufferDecodingStream (buffer, encodedLength);
    xdrOut.beginDecoding ();
    response.xdrDecode (xdrOut);
    xdrOut.endDecoding ();
    xdrOut.close ();
    return response;
  }
  catch (ConnectException ex)
  {

    ioException = ex;
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {

    ioException = ex;

    if (socket != null)
    {
      needResetPool = true;
      try { socket.close (); } catch (Throwable t) {}

      try
      {
        pool.invalidateObject (socket);          // Mark the socket as invalid

      }
      catch (Throwable t)
      {

      }
      socket = null;
    }
  }
  finally
  {    
    if (socket != null)
    {
      try
      {
        pool.returnObject (socket);
      }
      catch (Throwable t)
      {

      }
    }
  }

  if (attempts >= MAXIMUM_RETYR_BEFORE_RESET_POOL && needResetPool)
  {

    pool.clear (pool.getKey ()); // clean all connect for the current server id
  }
  if (attempts >= MAXIMUM_RETRY)
  {

    throw ioException;
  }

  attempts++;

} // while
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing while closing the connections?

The server isn't closing its sockets in response to reading EOS (read() returns -1). This code doesn't handle it well either. CLOSE_WAIT means that the peer has closed the connection and the local system is waiting for the application to close this end.

Comment: Hi EJP am updated above code & place if condition for EOS,but it won't work for me.Can you please elaborate more on this.
.......
if (bytesRead < UreMsgBodyLength.MESSAGE_HEADER_LEN)
          throw new IOException("Socket Read Failed - invalid bytesRead="+bytesRead);

        if((byte)bytesRead==-1){
         throw new IOException("END OF STREAM----------------------");
        }
        int encodedLength = bytesRead;
......

Comment: @rahulpoorey Code in comments is almost illegible,  but it should be `if (bytesRead == -1)`. Remove the cast. And put that test before the length test. In fact, *remove* the length test: convert it to a loop, or use `DataInputStream.readFully()`. TCP can deliver you any number of bytes at any time: you don't have any business throwing `IOExceptions` when your misplaced expectations about that are disappointed.